# Search values without repeating value of the first parameter

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm using xsl 1.0
I would like to get the respective values ​​of each parameter as xml below. 
Notes below my current results of the second parameter is the value of the first repeating.
Use the function only choose not to find value = 'null'

my xml:

```
<INDIVIDUO param='1' >
  <DATA>
    <f16>
      <ROW f1='Breast' f2='63'/>
     </f16>
</INDIVIDUO>
<INDIVIDUO param='2' >
  <DATA>
    <f16>
      <ROW f1='Beddle' f2='40'/>
    </f16>
</INDIVIDUO>
```

my xsl code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:rdf="http://xxx#" version="1.0">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<!--  Begin RDF document  -->
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:element name="rdf:RDF">
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://xxx">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</rdf:Description>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="f16">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="/INDIVIDUO/DATA/f16/ROW/@f1 !='NULL'">
            <xsl:element name="hasNameCancer" namespace="{namespace-uri()}#">
              <xsl:value-of select="/INDIVIDUO/DATA/f16/ROW/@f1" />
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>

        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="/INDIVIDUO/DATA/f16/ROW/@f2 !='NULL'">
            <xsl:element name="idadediag" namespace="{namespace-uri()}#">
              <xsl:value-of select="/INDIVIDUO/DATA/f16/ROW/@f2" />
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
```

My actual result:

```
<individuo_1>
    <hasNameCancer>Breast</hasNameCancer>
    <idadediag>63</idadediag>
  </individuo_1>

  <individuo_2>
    <hasNameCancer>Breast</hasNameCancer>
    <idadediag>63</idadediag>
  </individuo_2>
```

I wish the result would be:

```
<individuo_1>
    <hasNameCancer>Breast</hasNameCancer>
    <idadediag>63</idadediag>
  </individuo_1>

  <individuo_2>
    <hasNameCancer>Beddle</hasNameCancer>
    <idadediag>40</idadediag>
  </individuo_2>
```

Comment: Your XSLT does not match your XML example (which is invalid due to lack of root element).

Comment: It still doesn't match: `INDIVIDUAL` = `INDIVIDUO`?

Comment: was not only available but follows ...

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting the same results because you are not selecting the rows in the context of `f16`. You are always getting the first element because you are actually selecting the collection of *all* rows. Since your context is `f16` you can select the descendant nodes using relative expressions.

To select the element *in context*, use *relative* XPath expressions in your `test` and `select`:

```
<xsl:template match="f16">
    <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="ROW/@f1">
             <xsl:element name="hasNameCancer" namespace="{namespace-uri()}#">
                 <xsl:value-of select="ROW/@f1" />
             </xsl:element>
         </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    ...
```

Comment: Use the test function for not picking up values ​​= "null"

Comment: Do you test for the literal *string* "null"? If so, you should also change "NULL" to "null" (case matters). The code above tests if an attribute *exists*.

Comment: Hello Helder, thanks for your help. The problem is the repetition of the first value found for the other parameters in other nodes. In the example, the value found in the first line "Breast" <individuo_1> repeats the value found in the <individuo_2>.